# Using Card Image as Slider - Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to use card-image-top section as a slider, especially on mobile. I will use that part as product card and i want my customers to see several images on this part. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Example Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean a card carousel like: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VRWyR ?

Comment: Yeap, exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
<div class="card">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=4" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=5" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=6" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: hi @loremipsum, welcome to S/O, also add what was the issue how did you solve that, so it will helpful for upcoming users to identify their mistake